# SharePoint 2013 Find/Replace Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column

Was hoping someone could assist me with regards to SharePoint Calculated column.

I have an address column which has an `&`. We need to find and replace the `&` with `and`.

The problem is that the `&` is in different places all the time depending on the length of the address.

Is there something I can do in SharePoint 2013 to assist me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel this can be solved with `=SUBSTITUTE()`. However, this formula is not available in SharePoint and you have to use `=FIND()` and `=REPLACE()` to replace `=SUBSTITUTE()`.

If you only have one `&` (question is implying that this is the case), this can be easily achieved with `=REPLACE([column];FIND("&";[column]);1;"and")`. If you have to replace more than one `&`, you have to nest this code as many times in your function, as you expect a `&`.

Comment: ok when i try it out it says "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported." Seems the formula is right but i am doing something wrong

Comment: Try replacing all ";" with "," (semicolon to comma)

Answer (score 1):

How to replicate the  SUBSTITUTE() function behaviour with default SharePoint functions was explained here:

[Calculated Column Formula how to replace Substitute](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149491/calculated-column-formula-how-to-replace-substitute)