# Calculated Column - extract only letters

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated column [lastname] with the following formula:

```
=RIGHT([Staff Name],LEN([Staff Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Staff Name])))
```

[Staff Name] is generated by SharePoint Designer (from another list) which is basically concatenating the first and last name from an email address.

If two or more individuals share the same first and last names, a number is added to the last name. i.e. First.Last1@domain.com

Is there a way I can extract only the letters in the last name?

Comment: why you need to get the last name again in a calculated column, you already caught the last name in SharePoint designer that means it's already a column in your list ! !!

Comment: SPD creates a new item in another list. Is there a way I can get rid of the number in the last name from SPD?

Answer (score 0):

You *can*, but it would be better if you were able to retrieve the *identity* of that user from that other list and parse the data out that way. Much cleaner and less subject to loopholes than this would be.

A previous question ([here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156233/sharepoint-2013-find-replace-calculated-column)) that has discussed this and they have you just doing nested =REPLACE() functions.