# Replace second "?" with Calculated Column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

The string below contains two `"?"` what calculated column formula should I use to replace the second `"?"` with `"&"` but not remove the `"?"` from other strings that have only one "?"

Could anyone please provide the appropriate code to replace the second instance only of "?" in a string with a "&" ?

```
http://www.ipa.co.uk/cpd/coursedetails.aspx?courseid=275?utm_lead=pd&utm_format=qualification&utm_campaign=foundationcert17&utm_source=mailchimp&utm_medium=email
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
var index = input.IndexOf('?', input.IndexOf('?') + 1);
var ouput = string.Concat(input.Substring(0,index), "&", input.Substring(index + 1));
```

Or:

```
var output = new string(input.Select((c, i) => i == index ? '&' : c).ToArray());
```

Credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547100/replace-second-occurence-of-with-an

Comment: I'm looking to use a calculated formula. Can this work has a calculated formula? Thank you

Comment: Can you help with providing the appropriate code to replace the second instance only of "?" in a string with a "&" ?

Answer (score 0):

Get it working Excel first, saves you SP headaches
You only need the basic functions, and the syntax in SharePoint Formulas is the same

Here is a list of functions that work in SharePoint Formulas: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Pseudo code:

- Get the string **after** the first ?
- In that string replace the ?

Note: SharePoint has no `SUBSTITUTE` function to replace **all** characters,
you can do it with nested functions:

StackOverflow: [Calculated Column Formula how to replace Substitute](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149491/calculated-column-formula-how-to-replace-substitute)