# Count occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

I would like to find the number of values or commas in a single line of text column. For example if the entry is 1,5 ,10 I would like the count to return 3 (or 2 if counting commas).

I have tried using this logic:

`LEN([Probe Numbers]) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE([Probe Numbers],",",""))`

But there is no substitute in SharePoint. I have also tried using this instead of substitute `REPLACE([Probe Numbers],FIND(",",[Probe Numbers]),1,"")`, but that is only replacing the first comma not all, so the value won't be correct when subtracting lengths.

I cannot use InfoPath, trying to do this using just a calculated column

Comment: Do you want the count displayed in a View only, or do you need the count in other formulas or workflows?

Comment: In a column / calculated field

Answer (score 1):

You have to nest the REPLACE, replacing one occurrence every time.

I think you can nest 7 levels deep in one formula, if you need more spread the workload over multiple Calculated Columns

I have a private tool to built complex Formulas, if you do it step by step and working from a good text-editor you can do this by hand

[image]

If you only want to display the value you can use JavaScript

[Calculated Column Formula how to replace Substitute](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149491/calculated-column-formula-how-to-replace-substitute/149520#149520)