# SharePoint calculated column to search a character from the right side of the string

Tags: custom-list

I have a string field in sharepoint list. I wanted to use calculated column to extract the part of the text.

File Path: `Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/IBRegForm-1.doc`

I need to extract the string except the part from last "/ " character.

Result to be : `Folder1/Folder2/Folder3`

I also have checked this link. But it is not as my case.
[Using calculated field to retrieve substring of another field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field)

kindly help on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest 2 FINDs and 1 SUBSTR for every / . and nest that in an IF for every /

so your Formula for 3 slashes should at least have 6 FIND statements, 3 SUBSTR statements.

Start in Excel and make it work there (with only FIND and IF and SUBSTR )

**You can take inspiration for Nesting from this SO Answer: [Calculated Column Formula how to replace Substitute](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149491/calculated-column-formula-how-to-replace-substitute)**

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what if my string contains more slashes...is there any way to search the slash from right side of the string??